# What link to use on the web to make bada install an application?

Tags: mobile, smartphone, bada

Please help me with one thing: I need to be able to forward a bada device to a certain application store page. This page should let the device to install the application using its native installation method, just like Android market or iTunes.

Granted that I know the link to my [application](http://www.samsungapps.com/topApps/topAppsDetail.as?productId=G00000541866) on the web, where do I get the link to forward the device to?

I've tried to use the simulator's WebViewer application on the Samsung Apps site, but it can't even find the application that I want to link to.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at the links below.

using the namespace Osp::Commerce::Store, you can call the Samsung Apps within the app and encourage users to install apps via Samsung Apps. Hope it works for you.

http://developer.bada.com/article/Try-Purchase-using-In-App-Purchase
http://developer.bada.com/article/Implementation-Guide-for-Samsung-Apps-Try-and-Purchase-Feature

Comment: I fear that this is not what I need. I want to be able to link to the application in the store from outside of any application, on any web page.